# Removal of White Line on intersection of 2 quads in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on building a box that the user looks from the inside out, a sky box or some thing of the sort. I am doing this by taking 6 quads and creating a cube with them and then putting the theoretical camera inside the cube and texturing the cube with an image. The user can look around by using the mouse and the cube rotates making as seem that one is moving their head. i have run in to a problem with a white line appearing at the intersections of the two sides, I have tried pulling in the quads while keeping the size of the actual quads the same. i have made sure that the clear color was black and I am still getting the white line.

Here are the attributes I set:

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glClearDepth(1);
//S is the side length of the cube
float s = 5;
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);

glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);

glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

Here is the code that creates the cube:

```
float s = 5; //S is the side length of each quad
glNewList(m_cube, GL_COMPILE);
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        {
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

            glPushMatrix();
            {

                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                {

                    //front
                    {
                        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, (1.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //1

                        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, (1.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //2
                        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, (2.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //3
                        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, (2.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //4
                    }

                    //left
                    {
                        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, (1.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //2
                        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, (1.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //5
                        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, (2.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //6
                        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, (2.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //3
                    }

                    //right
                    {
                        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, (1.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //7
                        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, (1.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //1
                        glTexCoord2f(0.5f, (2.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //4
                        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, (2.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //8
                    }

                    //back
                    {
                        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, (1.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //5
                        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, (1.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //7
                        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, (2.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //8
                        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, (2.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //6
                    }

                    //top
                    {
                        glTexCoord2f(.5f, 1.0f);
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //7
                        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 1.0f);
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //5
                        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, (2.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //2
                        glTexCoord2f(.5f, (2.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), -((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //1
                    }

                    //bottom
                    {
                        glTexCoord2f(.5f, (1.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //4
                        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, (1.0f / 3.0f));
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   -((s / 2.0f))); //3
                        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.0f);
                        //       glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
                        glVertex3f(-((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //6
                        glTexCoord2f(.5f, 0.0f);
                        //       glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                        glVertex3f(((s / 2.0f)), ((s / 2.0f)),
                                   ((s / 2.0f))); //8
                    }

                }
                glEnd();

            }
            glPopMatrix();
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }
        glPopMatrix();
    }
    glEndList();
```

Here is the code that sets up the camara:

```
float near_ = 1f;
float far_ = 10.0f;

float halfHeight = near_ * (Radian(m_fov)) / 2.0f;
float halfWidth = (static_cast<float>((m_width)) / static_cast<float>((m_height))) * halfHeight;
glViewport(0, 0, m_width, m_height);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glFrustum(-halfWidth, halfWidth, -halfHeight, halfHeight, near_, far_);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Here is the code that renders to the screen:

```
void VideoStreamer::render()
{
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

float pitch = clamp(Degree(m_pitch), Degree(-(80.f)), Degree(80.f));
float yaw = wrap(m_yaw, Degree(0), Degree(360));
float roll = wrap(m_roll, Degree(0), Degree(360));
glPushMatrix();
{
    glLineWidth(5);
    glPushMatrix();
    {
        if (1)
        {
            glRotatef(pitch, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glRotatef(yaw, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            glRotatef(roll, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        }

        glCallList((m_cube));
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
glPopMatrix();
SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
}//end render
```

And here is a screen shot of what is happening, notice the white line between the blue and black quads:
[image]

Here is the texture I am using, resolution 600x450, but line happens at multiple resolutions:

[image]

My question is: How do I get rid of that white line?

EDIT: The white lines are only appearing where the top and bottom meet the left and right

EDIT: Updated Code to reflect suggestions

Comment: Are you culling the back-normal faces?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık No I am not doing any culling at all.

Comment: What happens when you rotate, does that line disappear then come back again? Can you also give info about glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glEdgeFlag(GL_FALSE); please? Why is edge_flag false?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık At times yes, at other times the line flickers. The point, line and polygon smooth are there because I thought it would help, but it did not help, the Edge flag is for boundary edge, and when I think of boundaries, I think of them as visible in my mind, but that is not the case here.

Comment: Could there be a possibility of line_smooth overrides polygon_smooth? Also, did you shut your OS's desktop antialiasing down? Could be interfering with your software i dont know

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık I just tried it out, with out the line smooth, point smooth and edge flag lines, still the same problem

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık I disable antialiasing that did not help, and I turned off lights and the clear color is black

Comment: But i cannot say anything for removal of z-fighting

Comment: Okay, according to your newly added texture, you must be having the problem between blue&black, blue&green, blue&red but not blue&gray

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık The problem is between blue and red, blue and black, green and red, and green and black.

Blue is my top, and Green is my bottom

Comment: I think i found the problem now. `glTexCoord2f(0.75f, (1.0f / 3.0f));` does 1/3 but s/3 somewhere else is not exactly 5x times of it according to floating point limits. s=5 right? what happens when you set s=5.0001. Try 0.33 instead of 1/3 and 1.65 instead of s/3 and see if it is Ok. If not, then we delve deeper into 3d things

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık I figured out the problem, some of the white was leaking into color in the texture, that was causing problems, I confirmed this by changing the empty space to black and seeing the white lines turn to black

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is simply that you indeed have white in your texture. So the fragments that are on the border of the face end up fetching from the white part (you'll see that more clearly if you turn a linear filter type on your texture).

What you can do to fix it:

1. duplicate the expected colors at the borders of your unwrapped cube texture (add red at left of blue, black at right, blue at top of red and black, and so on for the bottom part...)
2. Or better, switch your code to use a cubemap rather than a 2d map. They offer proper filtering at cube faces

Answer (score 3):

I couldnt give you this picture in the comment part so, can you increase the quad lengths while making them stay at same planar height like in this picture?

[image]

What was the float-precision in your GPU?

```
float near_ = 0.00000001f;
```

So you already tried :

[image]

What [screen sub-space division technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping) are you using?

[image]

Assumption: your dashed-line could be originated from [Z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)

**Z-fighting** is a phenomenon in 3D rendering that occurs when two or more primitives have similar values in the z-buffer. It is particularly prevalent with coplanar polygons, where two faces occupy essentially the same space, with neither in front. Affected pixels are rendered with fragments from one polygon or the other arbitrarily, in a manner determined by the precision of the **z-buffer**. It can also vary *as the scene or camera is changed, causing one polygon to "win" the z test*, then another, and so on. The overall effect is a **flickering, noisy rasterization of two polygons which "fight" to color the screen pixels**. This problem is usually caused by limited **sub-pixel precision** and floating point and **fixed point round-off errors**.

Comment: I have tried something like that, but my textures end up wrapping weirdly, but I am going to have to put that off for another time as I have to get to class soon

Comment: Your "near" float could be at the pricision limit . By the way, im working on solid-state physics now. See you couple hors later.

Comment: I just tried it at less pricision to .01f, and that did not change anything, the near value has to do with the way the frustum is created

Comment: Z-fight sounds like it could be the case

Comment: Make the camera's near clip plane as big as possible, and the far clip plane as small as possible, so the depth buffer's precision isn't wasted. Eric5h5's answer from unity developers network

Comment: I moved the top and bottom sides outward for a quick test to see if the lines would go away because there is not an intersection and the lines were still there, any ideas?

Comment: Hmmmm. What texture are you using? glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP); what if gl_clamp is intersecting with desktop-defaults?

Comment: Check newest update for texture I am using, and I am not sure what you mean by desktop-defaults

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the fact that the texture was having a texture leak that was getting border colors between sides. My math was right in the sides and put the texture texels, but there is float point errors that are happening that I can fix.

Comment: You could accept Bahbar's answer instead, since it seems to address the correct problem and also provides good solutions. Anyway, congrats on solving your problem!

Answer (score 1):

That looks quite a bit like scintillation, which is almost always caused by rounding errors.  The sizes of your quads look prefectly reasonable, but the value of your near-plane is quite small. This is likely causing large rounding errors when you multiply the verticies by the MVP matrix. Try setting the near plane to `.1f`.

**EDIT** Otherwise, check your vertex creation code for a possible Bug. It was a bit hard for me to follow - for exapmle, the top face is calculated using `-((s / 2.0f)-.1),` - Why are you subtracting .1?

Perhaps writing a new function to create the vertices and hard-coding in values would be a quick way to test if this is the problem or not.

Comment: @btaidm Regardless, I wouldn't set your near-plane value much less than .001, and even that is pushing it. I've edited my answer with a new possible solution [possible bug in vertex creation code].

Comment: I changed the near plane to 1 and updated the quad size up to 5, and brought the far plane in to 10, but the line did not go away.